# How to implement trigger in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

Is there any good example or guide on how to implement a Cassandra trigger step-by-step?

I'm looking for something advanced, like manipulating other rows in same partition after an INSERT or UPDATE is performed.

Unfortunately the documentation is very limited, I only found these links so far:

- [Official documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/triggers.html)
- [Documentation at DataStax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html)
- [Example
  implementation in official repo](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java)

## Example

Let's say you want to put logs into a table and aggregate them whenever you reach a certain number of log entries.

```
CREATE TABLE simple_log (
    id int,
    event_id timeuuid,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO simple_log (id, event_id, message) VALUES (1, now(), 'first');
INSERT INTO simple_log (id, event_id, message)  VALUES (1, now(), 'second');
INSERT INTO simple_log (id, event_id, message)  VALUES (1, now(), 'third');
```

Whenever you select top the logs by ID, you should get back an aggregated result:

```
SELECT * FROM simple_log WHERE id = 1;

 id | event_id                             | message
----+--------------------------------------+---------
  1 | d97f92d1-b5a4-11e7-825c-495e6ea8608a |   first-second-third
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way. Cassandra doesn't have the rich option set that more mature database systems do. Also, consider the distributed nature of Cassandra. Where would the trigger run? What would the trigger be permitted to do?

Comment: @MarcBernier - Why do they include it in the documentation then? I'm not sure if there's a plan to introduce richer trigger functionality, but in some cases when you want to extend database it can become useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add mutations to manipulate other rows into the collection of mutations like in the example.

Both it and CDC do not have a whole lot of documentation around it because its generally recommended not to use them unless *really* needed. Theres a lot of complexity in distributed systems with things like this and it can usually be reasoned better in your application layer.

Why not just include the other mutations in an batch? especially in same partition it will likely work far better and require less effort in things like keeping trigger deployed on all instances in sync and updated etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm mainly looking for the capabilities of triggers and how to implement them properly. Main issue with batches is that CQL operations might not be able to do complex tasks, like merging rows in a partition after inserting new values. I will try to add an example for my question.

Comment: in your example, i would recommend adding event_id as a clustering index `PRIMARY KEY(id, event_id)` and add `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_id DESC)` then you can `SELECT * FROM simple_log WHERE id = '1'` and it will give you first, second, third as the top 3 logs, you can just aggregate that in your application without triggers. If its just for browsing cqlsh, you can just look at them that way. Alternatively could consider a static column in the partition that is a "slug" of the data, and you can use LWTs on your insert to append your string to it until it reaches current size etc.