# Is it possible to track row updates on a Cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra

I have a distributed service where each node running the service is also hosting a Cassandra node for the database used by the service.  If a node goes down, when it comes back up the process of re-syncing the service is very expensive.  I've found a way to optimize the process, but it involves monitoring the updates to the Cassandra instance on the same node.

As an example, say I had a table of clients:

```
CREATE TABLE Clients(id int, name text, status text)
```

When a row gets updated/inserted, the info is written to a local file on each node. If a node goes down, when it comes back up, the local Cassandra database will receive updates to the table that were made in its absence. I want to monitor these these updates and use them to update the local files.

I've been looking at triggers, but I haven't been able to find much documentation. Answers and comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837731/how-to-implement-trigger-in-cassandra), seem to indicate Triggers should be avoided. But that question is from 5 1/2 years ago.

Can I use Triggers to accomplish what I need? Is there documentation that details how to write a trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra triggers should still be avoided.  Writing a trigger involves building a Java class into a JAR, and adding that JAR to each node in your cluster.  I've done it; do not recommend.

To me, the right solution here sounds like using CDC with Apache Pulsar.  Essentially, you enable CDC on a table and build a Pulsar connector.  This way, all mutations sent to that table are put on to a Pulsar topic.  You can then read those mutations by building a consumer to watch the topic, read the messages on the topic, and write it to a (local) file of your choosing.

Here's a doc that takes you through that process.  It's meant for K8ssandra, but if you skip the Kubernetes-specific steps the process is the same: https://docs.k8ssandra.io/tasks/cdc/

This helps you build a sample Pulsar consumer: https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/2.11.x/client-libraries-java/#consumer

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible to do that in Cassandra and it sounds like a perfect use case for Change Data Capture (CDC).

CDC logging captures and tracks mutations (inserts, updates, deletes), storing them in a log that is the same format as Cassandra commit logs. Your app can then "consume" the CDC logs either by using a `CommitLogReader` (see [Change Data Capture](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/operating/cdc.html) on the Apache Cassandra website), or by streaming the data with Apache Pulsar.

I don't have a readily-available streaming example but if you want to see it in action, this [CDC for Astra DB](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/astream-cdc.html) document will walk you through how to setup a free Pulsar tenant + topic on [Astra Streaming](https://www.datastax.com/products/astra-streaming) then connect it to a free Cassandra cluster on [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) with CDC enabled for streaming. It's all on the free tier so there's no credit card required to set it up.

As a side note, CQL Triggers were added in Cassandra 2.0 as an experimental feature but it hasn't been actively developed for years so I don't recommend deploying it in production. Cheers!